# The f4m document contains errors URL missing from media tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, flash-media-server, aws-cloudformation

Sorry if this is in the wrong place.

I’ve gone through Amazon’s guide to setting up a live stream using CloudFront and Flash Media Server as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingAdobeFMS4.5.html

However, when I get to configuring Flash Media Playback setup I get the following message:

> The f4m document contains errors
>   URL missing from media tag

I copied the `LiveHDSManifest` value as pasted it in the **Video Source** field as described. What am I doing wrong?